# Question on counting functions satisfying a relation

Tags: discrete-mathematics

I have been assigned the following problem:

> Let A = {1, 2, 3, 4} and let F be the set of all functions from A to A. Let R be the relation defined by:
>
> > For all $f, g \in F$,  $(f,g)\in R$ if and only if $f(i) = g(i)$ for some $i \in A$.
>
> Let $\alpha(x) = 1$ and $\beta(x) = 2$ for all $x\in A$. How many $f\in F$ are there such that $(f,\alpha)\in R$ and $(f,\beta)\in R$?

I am unsure how to count this. I understand that $\alpha$ maps every value in A to 1, and $\beta$ maps all values to 2, so any $f\in R$ must map at least 1 value to 1 and at least 1 value to 2. However, as there are no restrictions on the function (it does not have to be an injection or a surjection) I don't know how to calculate this.

Any help would be very appreciated.

Comment: I would think  $f(i)=\alpha(i)$ means $f(1)=\alpha(1)$, $f(2)=\alpha(2)$, $f(3)=\alpha(3)$...

Comment: The relation applies if it's any of those, unless I am sorely mistaken. The two functions $f, \alpha$ are related if and only if one equals the other for some $i\in A$, not (necessarily) for all $i\in A$.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You might rephrase the counting problem as counting the total number of maps, and then counting the number of maps that either fail to take on the value 1 or fail to take on the value 2 (some care is needed to count this set properly, see [this](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Inclusion%E2%80%93exclusion_principle) if you want a general approach).  The difference between the first quantity and the second quantity will be your answer.